# Magento 2 currency rates not imported

Tags: php, magento2, currency

I am trying to enable more currencies and then try to import rates from web service in **Magento 2**.

When I do

```
Stores > Currency > Currency Rates > Import
```

It shows following error:

> We can't retrieve a rate from http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=INR&ToCurrency=GBP.
>
> We can't retrieve a rate from http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=INR&ToCurrency=USD.

I also do search for same issue but cant find solution.

Comment: Looks like webservicex.net is no longer performing currency conversions in that format. See also: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Technical-Issues/Webservicex-don-t-update-currency/td-p/22337

Comment: I already show this post. But looking for  solution or alternative @bishop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you visit that URL, you'll notice it says:

```
{"code":"PAGE_NOT_FOUND","message":"Page not found"}
```

Not good. If you then go to webservicex.net and scroll through its list of API, you'll notice that none refer to currency conversion. Also, not good.

If you web search for currency import in Magento 2, you'll come to this [shopgo module](https://github.com/shopgo-magento2/currency-import-services), which says:

> Magento 2.0's default and only currency import service WebserviceX tends to go down from time to time. And sometimes, it returns empty results for some currencies.

Three times the charm: webservicex.net is probably not going to work. Try installing the module from shopgo, which uses other providers.